# Mysql logging in even without providing password

Tags: mysql

mysql logging in the prompt even not providing password , 
If provided like `mysql -u root -p` its prompting for password 
if provided like `mysql -u root` its logging in without asking for password 
i have run the query

```
select user,hosts from mysql.user;
```

and came to know there are 3 root users with different hosts as shown

```
+------+-------------+
| user | host        |
+------+-------------+
| root | 127.0.0.1   |
| root | db-busindia |
| root | localhost   |
+------+-------------+
```

And interesting thing is that mysql server name is also db-busindia , is `root@'db-busindia'` the culprit ?

Comment: Please show us: `select host,user,password from mysql.user;`

Comment: I cannot show you the passwords even they are md5 encrypted , but ya there is no empty value for any of these root users

Answer (score 3):

Check the [client] section of my.cnf file for the lines:

```
user=root 
password=some text.
```

These enable you to log in without a username or password. Delete `password` line, if you want to be prompted for password.

Comment: what you are saying is because of that mentioning password in my.cnf in client , you can even login without password even from the server ? If that so i need to check . please confirm @user4035

Comment: @mViswa Yes, you can login without the password, even without the user. If the default user/password is set in my.cfg. Check the file, please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even I've encountered this issue long ago. Usually we encounter them while installing  MySQL server where all your client connections establish connection using socket. You can simply check its Plugin under mysql.user table.

```
Ubuntu@localhost:~# mysql 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root             | localhost | auth_socket           |
| mysql.session    | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+

mysql> update mysql.user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user = 'root';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

You can disable that option by updating plugin value to 'mysql_native_password '.

```
Ubuntu@localhost:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Ubuntu@localhost:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allow us to login without passing the `user` and `password` by putting the `user` and `password` in `my.cnf`.

```
$ mysql
```

Please check the `my.cnf` which usually in `/etc/mysql/` or if you have overrides you can find it in `~/.my.cnf`. Just remove the `user` and `password`.

See something like this:

```
user=root
password=35620fhgf8025ec31ffd2c1
host=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after running mysql_secure_installation on a Debian 9 running MariaDB. Gazzar's answer on Oct 14, 2017 to the 'can't log in as mysql user root...' post [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04/801950) led me to look at the plugin field on the mysql.users table with this sql statement:

> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;

If you see 'auth.socket' (on mysqldb) or 'unix.socket' (mariadb), you can try modifying the entry to 'mysql_native_password' with an update statement like this:

> UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'root';

After I made this change, I could login in from any account with the command:

> mysql -u root -p

as long as I entered the correct password. And if I used the command:

> sudo mysql

I was still asked for the root password.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command to access your MySQL command.

```
sudo mysql
```